# How to calculate how many recursive calls happened in this Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now. 
I need to calculate how many recursive calls happened using a certain function:

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
maximum' [] = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximum' [x] = x  
maximum' (x:xs)   
    | x > maxTail = x  
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = maximum' xs
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's not the most convenient thing, but you could change your function to take an extra argument, in which you'll store current recursion depth, and to return tuple `(actualResult, finalRecursionDepth)`.

Comment: This is actually what I need. can you please elaborate. @Michail

Comment: I have written an answer. It's a bit too big to place it in a comment (even if max comment length allows it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you love functional programming? Do you love imperative programming? Why not have both! Here's a recursive-imperative way to count the recursion depth.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.State

maximumWithCount :: (Ord a, MonadState Int m) => [a] -> m a
maximumWithCount xs = case xs of
  [] -> error "empty list"
  [x] -> return x
  (x:xs) -> do
    modify (+1)  -- increment the counter because we're recursing!
    y <- maximumWithCount xs
    return $ max x y

λ runState (maximumWithCount [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]) 0
(5,8)
```

Comment: Using `Writer (Sum Int)` is probably more appropriate than `State Int`

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your function to carry information about recursion depth in an extra argument, and return it as second (or first, if you so prefer) element of a tuple:

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int -> (a, Int)
maximum' [] _ = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximum' [x] n = (x, n)
maximum' (x:xs) n   
    | x > fst maxTail = (x, snd maxTail)
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = maximum' xs (n + 1)
```

Then you can call the function with `maximum' lst 0` or `maximum' lst 1` depending on whether or not you want the first call to count as a recursion level.

It can be done with any recursive function, but it's probably not necessary in your case. As chepner wrote, the answer is known without extra computations.

Comment: Carrying the depth is useful both for informational purposes and, in some cases, necessary for implementing the function. (Bounded depth-first search of a tree comes to mind.)

Answer (score 2):

For a list with `n` elements, there are `n-1` recursive calls. To make it easier to see, we'll rewrite the function slightly. (We can ignore empty list for this.)

```
maximum' [x] = x
maximum' (x:xs) = if x > maxTail then x else maxTail
                  where maxTail = maximum' xs
```

A recursive call is made when the tail of the argument is not empty. (Note that a function that was defined for the empty list as well would make `n` recursive calls on a list with `n` items.)

We can expand a call to a 3-item list, for example:

```
maximum' [1,2,3] = if 1 > maxTail then 1 else maxTail where maxTail = maximum' [2,3]
 maximum' [2,3] = if 2 > maxTail then 2 else maxTail where maxTail = maximum' [3]
  maximum' [3] = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a digression on **Michail**'s and **user2297560**'s answers.

What if, instead of rewriting the function from scratch to add tracking functionality, we could reuse the original implementation and "instrument" it in some way?

We could write a base function that

- Is monadic, but polymorphic on the monad.
- Is defined using anonymous recursion, with the help of `fix`.

For example:

```
import Data.Function(fix)
import Data.Functor.Identity

maximumAux :: (Monad m,Ord a) 
           => ([a] -> m a) 
           ->  [a] -> m a  
maximumAux _ [] = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximumAux _ [x] = return x  
maximumAux recurse (x:xs) = 
    do maxTail <- recurse xs
       return (max x maxTail)

maximumPure :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximumPure as = runIdentity (fix maximumAux as)
```

And then instrument it like this, reusing the original logic:

```
maximumInstrumented :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> IO a
maximumInstrumented = fix (instrument maximumAux)
    where
    instrument auxf iorecurse as = 
        do print $ "starting call with params " ++ show as
           a <- auxf iorecurse as
           print $ "ending call with value" ++ show a
           return a
```

But perhaps defining functions as "monadic by default" isn't too practical.