# Is there any way to print a variable inside a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, mergesort

I am a beginner in Haskell who has a background in imperative languages, and I wanted to know if it was possible to print in a Haskell function and not print in the main.

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x < y = x:(merge xs (y:ys))
    | otherwise = y:(merge (x:xs) ys)
```

I wanted to see the list's contents after every merge operation, but an error occurs when I tried inserting a `print` statement in this function. This code is part of a program that does a merge sort operation, so I cannot place a print statement in the main function. I would use the ghci, and compile the merge function from a separate file to manually see how the merge function works, but I became curious if it was possible to see the list's contents in the merge function itself.

How would I show the contents of the list given this merge function? Do I need to recode the whole merge function in another way to see the contents of the list? If so, how would it look like?

Comment: You might like to use the [`traceShow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShow) function

Comment: A possible trick two print intermediate values when you need it, while not forcing you into `IO` when you dont: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791334/1364288 The disadvantage is that it forces you to work polymorphically over a monad, and you must write the recursion in an "open" way—only to close it later with `fix`, once the "instrumentation" has been inserted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general: no, you cannot print from just any function in Haskell. This is because normal Haskell functions cannot have any side-effects, of which printing is an example. (Other side-effects: mutating a variable, playing sound, sending a HTTP request.) Any side-effect in Haskell must be wrapped in an `IO` type, so if you want to use `print` in this function, you must wrap the whole function in `IO`:

```
merge1 :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> [a] -> IO [a]
merge1 [] ys = return ys
merge1 xs [] = return xs
merge1 (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x < y =
        let merged = x:(merge1 x (y:ys)) in do
            print merged
            return merged
    | otherwise =
        let merged = y:(merge1 (x:xs) ys) in do
            print merged
            return merged
```

As you can see, this is horribly verbose. It also means that `merge1` must be wrapped in `IO`, so any other function which uses it must also be in `IO`. (This is in fact often seen as an advantage, since it allows you to deduce the behaviour of a function from its type: it means that any function not in `IO` cannot have side effects, and *vice versa*.)

However, in your particular case, there is an escape route. The [`Debug.Trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html) module contains a whole bunch of functions for printing to the console *without* `IO`, to be used for debugging purposes only. The basic function is `trace s x`, which will print the string `s` to the console and return `x`. In your case, I suggest using `traceShowId x`, which will print `x`, then return it:

```
merge2 :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge2 [] ys = ys
merge2 xs [] = xs
merge2 (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x < y = traceShowId $ x:(merge2 x (y:ys))
    | otherwise = traceShowId $ y:(merge2 (x:xs) ys)
```

Comment: You need a `Show` constraint for that.

Comment: @dfeuer Whoops, I do indeed! I’ll fix that now.

Comment: I tried running it with the merge sort program and it showed an error with the traceShowId

Comment: @angelolunar Perhaps you need to `import Debug.Trace`? (Though I did just notice a small problem with `merge2`, I’ll fix it now.)

Comment: @bradrn I have already imported Debug.Trace and have tried compiling it, but the error points to the first parameter of merge2, which is x.

Comment: @angelolunar Hmm, I just tried it out, and it looks like my code does indeed give such an error — but your original code also gives exactly the same error. Since I just copied your code and added `traceShowId`, it looks like the error was originally in your code, and I then carried this error over to my code. Anyway, it appears to be just a small typo — looks like you wrote `x` instead of `xs` in the line starting `| x < y`.

Comment: @bradrn oh you're right, thanks. Can I know the syntax of traceShowId?  I haven't really understood it yet. And what's its difference if I use this instead of using the trace method?

Comment: @angelolunar `traceShowId` is just a function. You can call it in exactly the same way you call any other function — `traceShowId theValueYouWantToPrint`. As for the difference between `trace` and `traceShowId`: `trace` is the ‘underlying’ function, so to speak, with `traceShowId x = trace (show x) x`.

Comment: @bradrn I forget, but what is the significance of putting $ before x when you called traceShowId?

Comment: @angelolunar `$` is a very common operator in Haskell, defined in the Prelude as `f $ x = f x` — that is, it’s simply an explicit form of function application. The nice thing about `$` is that it has very low precedence, so it can often be used instead of parentheses. In this case, `traceShowId $ y:(merge2 (x:xs) ys)` is equivalent to `traceShowId (y:(merge2 (x:xs) ys))`. For more information, see http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application.