# Easiest way to debug/visualize recursive function calls in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning Haskell and I decided to implement this simple algorithm for doing part of the insert sort algorithm:

```
while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
    swap A[j] and A[j-1]
    j ← j - 1
end while
```

I did like this:

```
miniSort:: (Eq(a), Ord(a)) => Int -> [a] -> [a]
miniSort j list = if (list !! j) < (list !! (j-1)) && j >0
        then miniSort (j-1) (swapElements j (j-1) list) 
        else list
```

It was kinda hard to get it right but I did (I guess).

While in imperative programming languages to view each step I could simply do

```
while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
    print("j is $j")
    print("swapping $A[j] with $A[j-1]")
    swap A[j] and A[j-1]
    print("swapped list: $A")
    j ← j - 1
end while
print("ended with j $j")
```

On Haskell it's much much harder to insert logging functionality through the Writer Monad. I didn't even try because it would be a mess, and then when I wanted to clean the logging things it would be another mess.

Isn't there a way to view the function calls branching in Haskell?

For example:

```
miniSort 3 [1,2,4,3,7,8,5]
```

Would expand to something like this:

```
miniSort 3 [1,2,4,3,7,8,5] = if (3) < 4 && 3 >0
        then miniSort (2) [1,2,3,4,7,8,5]
miniSort 2 [1,2,3,4,7,8,5] = if (3) < 2 && 2 >0
        else [1,2,3,4,7,8,5]
[1,2,3,4,7,8,5]
```

Comment: Take a look at [trace](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.14/base-4.14.1.0/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace)

Comment: One solution (which would likely be overkill and difficult to understand for a beginner, so take it with a grain of salt) is to make your function monadic but polymorphic over the monad, and also write it in an "anonymous recursion" style which uses the auxiliary `fix` function. Then you could add or remove "instrumentation" by tweaking the recursion step. An example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781460/how-to-calculate-how-many-recursive-calls-happened-in-this-haskell-function/41791334#41791334

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Fyodor Soikin said, [`trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) inserts debug messages into arbitrary code, which will be printed when the statement you apply it to is evaluated.

```
import Debug.Trace
import Text.Printf

miniSort j list
 = if trace (printf "miniSort %i %s = if %i < %i && %i>0"
                              j (show list) (list!!j) (list!!(j-1)) j)
                      $ list !! j < list !! (j-1) && j>0
    then trace (printf "then miniSort %i %s" (j-1) (show list))
           miniSort (j-1) (swapElements j (j-1) list) 
    else traceShowId list
```

However, a couple of caveats:

- If you find yourself wanting this for a simple algorithm like a sort, you're doing something wrong. Which indeed you are – it makes no sense to sort a list like that in Haskell. Specifically, *indexing into lists* is almost never a good idea: it's awkward, error-prone and slow.
  Good Haskell code generally uses pattern matching instead of indexing etc.. For example,

  ```
  type SortedList a = [a]

  insertion :: Ord a => a -> SortedList a -> SortedList a
  insertion n (x:xs)
   | n>x    = x : insertion n xs
  insertion n xs = n : xs

  insertSort :: Ord a => [a] -> SortedList a
  insertSort [] = []
  insertSort (x:xs) = insertion x $ insertSort xs
  ```

  See, no indices anywhere. Much less that can go wrong here.
  (Whether it makes any sense to implement insertion sort on Haskell lists in the first place is of course another matter!)
- Because (non-monadic) Haskell doesn't really specify any evaluation order, `trace` can often come out in unexpected, possibly jumbled order. Really, only use it for debugging a single detail in the middle of a big, already-existing function. In general it's much better to instead refactor and unit-test thoroughly.
  And *never* use `trace` for actual logging!
- Using the writer monad not only solves these problems, it also makes it *easier* (and much more reliable) to remove such statements again. For one thing, you don't really *need* to do that at all because you can just ignore the log data, use a polymorphic monad with dummy logging that will optimise it away from being generated in the first place, etc.. If you do remove the statements and un-writer the type, then the type checker will highlight any places where you forgot to do it.

Comment: Can the strictness analyzer really look through all of your functions and remove the logging when it determines that your main program never reads? I would expect it to still create a thunk that determines what string to log, which could be even worse than generating strings to log because it retains your domain objects in memory to create a string if anyone ever asks for one.

Comment: You're right, that was phrased a bit too simplistic.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: this solution is overkill and not suitable for beginners. For practical advice, follow leftaroundabout's answer.

We can define minisort as a monadic function, but one which is polymorphic over the monad. Also, we'll define it using "open recursion", which means that the function receives its own recursion step as a *parameter*, instead of directly calling itself. This opens a seam into which we'll be able to insert instrumentation later:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

-- some helper type synonyms
type Minisort m a = Int -> [a] -> m [a]
type Open f = f -> f

minisortAux :: (Eq a, Ord a, Monad m) => Open (Minisort m a)
minisortAux recurse j list =
    if (list !! j) < (list !! (j-1)) && j >0
        then recurse (j-1) (swapElements j (j-1) list) 
        else pure list
```

We can recover the original `minisort` by choosing the no-op [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity) as the monad, and "closing" the recursion using [`Data.Function.fix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix):

```
import Control.Monad.Identity

minisort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => Int -> [a] -> [a]
minisort j list = runIdentity $ fix minisortAux j list
```

But we can also instrument the function so that it works in `IO` and prints its parameters at each iteration:

```
-- An Instrumentation transforms an open function into
-- another open function with extra behaviour.
-- Notice that instrumentations of the same type can be composed!
type Instrumentation f = Open f -> Open f

minisortIO :: forall a. (Eq a, Ord a, Show a) => Minisort IO a
minisortIO j list = fix (instrument minisortAux) j list 
  where
    instrument :: Instrumentation (Minisort IO a)
    instrument openFunction recurse j list = 
        do print $ "starting call with params " ++ show j ++ "  " ++ show list
           r <- openFunction recurse j list
           print $ "ending call with value" ++ show r
           return r
```

Or we could accumulate the parameters using `Writer`:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

minisortWriter :: forall a. (Eq a, Ord a) => Minisort (Writer [(Int,[a])]) a
minisortWriter j list = fix (instrument minisortAux) j list 
  where
    instrument :: Instrumentation (Minisort (Writer [(Int,[a])]) a)
    instrument openFunction recurse j list = 
        do tell [(j,list)]
           openFunction recurse j list
```

Besides printing or logging stuff, we could do things like asking the user  mid-recursion for the value of a parameter, or even let the user enter some result value for a recursive call and avoid doing the call altogether.

Comment: this is very cool, I'll read carefully, thank you so much!

Comment: "Functional Pearl: The Decorator Pattern in Haskell" http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~ntc2/haskell-decorator-paper.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic, but you would be better off learning to write idiomatic Haskell code
than trying to shoe-horn an impure, iterative algorithm into Haskell.

```
-- insert a value into a sorted list, preserving the sort
insert :: Ord a => [a] -> a -> [a]
insert [] y = [y]
insert (x:xs) y | x < y = x : insert xs y
                | otherwise = y : x : xs


-- sort a list by repeated inserting the first item of the list
-- into its proper place in the sorted remnant.
insSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
insSort [] = []
insSort (x:xs) = insert (insSort xs) x
```

The whole business with swapping is just how you would implement `insert` in a more imperative language; it's not how you would do it in Haskell.

Comment: Indeed. But I was implementing an specific algorithm. Do you think I could do it in a more functional way than that? I think the nature of the algorithm is not functional

Comment: The algorithm is "pick an element, and insert it into a sorted list". The imperative code you showed is one way to *implement* that algorithm. It's not something you would do in Haskell (or at least, not using a regular list; there are mutable `IORef` values that you can use to simulate mutable values more accurately). What I show here is, I think, a more functional way of implementing insertion sort. The difference is that you are building a new list, rather than reusing the input list to store both the sorted and unsorted portions of the input.

Comment: Is it really about imperative vs functional? I think it's more about lazy lists vs mutable indexed arrays. If one wanted to sort a mutable vector in-place in Haskell, some typical imperative algorithm would be reasonable, no?

Comment: @chepner indeed, this opened my mind. I was annoyed that my code looked very imperative

Comment: @amalloy Sure, but I don't think the OP is ready to worry about sorting mutable vectors in-place yet.